# JQuery: Update hover on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hoverimage").hover(
    function(e) { openQuicktip(this,e); },
    function() { closeQuicktip(this); }
  );

  $("area").hover(
    function(e) { openQuicktip(this,e); },
    function() { closeQuicktip(this); }
  );
});

function openQuicktip(elem,e) {
  ar x = e.pageX;
  ar y = e.pageY;

  $('.helpbox').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.helpbox').css('top', y).css('left', x);
  $('.helpbox .desc').html($(elem).attr('alt'));
}

function closeQuicktip($elem) {
  $('.helpbox').fadeOut('fast');
}
```

This is my jQuery, how do I make it "change" the coords each time i move the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mousemove event.

```
$("area").mousemove(function(e) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    $('.helpbox').css('top', y).css('left', x);
});
```

Also might consider adding a global variable that holds the open/close state of the QuickTip. And only update .helpbox if QuickTip is open.

..fredrik

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("area, .hoverimage").mousemove(function(e) {
        openQuicktip(this, e);
    });
    $("area, .hoverimage").mouseout(function(e) {
        closeQuicktip(this);
    });
});
function openQuicktip(elem,e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    $('.helpbox').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.helpbox').css('top', y).css('left', x + 10 );
    $('.helpbox .desc').html($(elem).attr('alt'));
}
```

function closeQuicktip($elem) {
    $('.helpbox').fadeOut('fast');
}

Comment: Good that it worked out. But you should really split the open method and move method so the effect and html methods isn't invoked every time you move the mouse. It's a waste of memory and CPU.

Comment: Thanks - that is what i did afterwards :)